# Getting runtime error:9 features not implemented error while using XmlSec Static library

Tags: c, xmlsec

I am facing one runtime error `"CryptoAppInit:error=9:feauter is not implemented: Crypto initialization failed while using XmlSec static library.` I made the xmlsec static library using Qt creator on Ubuntu(Linux). The other dependency libraries also static like (libxml, openssl). I need to have static library because of code integrity check on my safety project. Could you please help me to resolve the issue.